# multiple VM vs multiple named instance

Tags: sql-server-2008, database, sql

I am looking for some comparison or data for sql 2008 deployment , what are the advantages and disadvantages installing multiple VM vs multiple named instance ?

How can i save license cost using VMs vs physical server for sql 2008 ?

is there a way to find out what is maximum number of connections to database at any time or in the past - need to calculate needed CAL license ?

Thanks.

Comment: Connections != CAL - the number of connections is irrelevant. Distinct licensed users may open more than one connection.

Comment: Not related the the licensing question, there are significant performance implications for running IO intensive tasks like SQL2008 in VMs. Depending on your application(s) this might be a greater issue than the difference in CAL costs.

Comment: Here's a question by SQLRockstar that covers a lot of the benefits of virtualizing: http://serverfault.com/questions/25840/virtual-vs-named-sql-instances.

Comment: I have 245 number of connections ( maximum at a given time), what is the best way to license my sql server 2008 ? i have two CPU with multiple core, i may go VM on sql server not decided yet.

thx

Answer (score 1):

You can't have more than 50 instances on a single server, and the practical limit is probably lower than that, each instance will have a fair amount of memory overhead; if you're going to run multiple instances, you need to be sure to manage your memory; if you just use the defaults, all the instances will consume as much as needed and you'll have a performance nightmare.

If you buy the Enterprise edition of SQL and license per processor, you can scale VM's out pretty far, certainly beyond 50.

But a lot depends on the application, size of the database, growth rate, your budget, etc.

Comment: +1. The very expensive processor licensing can actually become quite a cost saver if you make good use of virtual SQL servers with it.

Comment: If i have around 250 user connecting to the server, is it a good idea to purchase an enterprise processor license or just go for CAL license only ? ( keeping in mind creating 5 or 6 sql8 VMs on the same box ? please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to use VM's they are going to take up more resources? Additionally each VM will require its own license. Use named instances. I believe you can have multiple named instances with one license.
Hope that answers your licensing issues as well as your deployment scenario.

Check out the licensing section of the [SQL Server 2008 Licensing Frequently Asked Questions](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/licensing-faq.aspx) site all your CAL answers are very clearly outlined in the first few Licensing questions.

Comment: Actually, if you license all sockets in a physical box, you can install SQL Server 2008 on as many VMs in that box as you want. It's in the virtualization section of the EULA.

Comment: Also, to find out why you'd want to use VMs, read Brent's post from my comment above. There's quite a few advantages to using VMs depending on what you're trying to do.